# Keep mod_security messages out of Apache's error_log, letting it use a separate file

Tags: apache2, mod-security2

Having set up a new server, I'm now running v2 of mod_security. I was able to convert all my rules to the new format, and everything seems to run fine so far. Just one thing I didn't manage is to have mod_security using its own logs (instead of logging to Apache's `error_log`). With v1.9 I was at least able to duplicate the messages, defining an additional log file with

```
CustomLog /path/to/modsec_log "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b %{mod_security-message}i" env=mod_security-relevant
```

But not even that works anymore. I couldn't find anything browsing the questions tagged [mod-security2](/questions/tagged/mod-security2), aunt Google didn't turn up any useful hints either. Is there anything I might have missed?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean the audit and debug logs? I have them set at modsec2.conf like this

```
SecAuditLog logs/modsec_audit.log
SecDebugLog logs/modsec_debug_log
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, bberg – but no. Those are separate logs, and I at least use the SecAuditLog that way from the beginning. As for SecDebugLog, mod_security's docu holds: *Messages at levels 1–3 are always copied to the Apache error log* (see SecDebugLogLevel). Those records are what I wanted to get to a separate file. But you're correct in so far that using SecDebugLog I could *duplicate* those records, as described for v1.9 with my question ;)

Answer (score 2):

In the `modsecurity_crs_10_setup.conf` file (on my configuration under `/usr/share/modsecurity-crs`) you can disable the logs on Apache `error.log`

```
# -- [[ Alert Logging Control ]] --
# You have three options -
#
# - To log to both the Apache error_log and ModSecurity audit_log file use: "log"
# - To log *only* to the ModSecurity audit_log file use: "nolog,auditlog"
# - To log *only* to the Apache error_log file use: "log,noauditlog"
```

Just change `SecDefaultAction` to

```
SecDefaultAction "phase:1,deny,nolog,auditlog"
```

Comment: Thanks (and +1) – that helps keeping the entries out of Apache's error log, which is half of the job. Unfortunately, it doesn't solve the other half (moving those entries to a separate log). Not that urgent anymore, though – whithin the last two years I got used to having them where they are ;)

Comment: This seems to be out of date, the modern equivalent of this file seems to be /etc/modsecurity/crs/crs-setup.conf but making the change there doesn't fully solve the problem, I think you need to edit a couple of the rules as well.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Logpath in the `modsecurity.conf` file  as follows:

```
SecAuditLog /root/...path../logs/modsec_audit.log   ( Relative Path )
```

Comment: What should that solve [bberg's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19630180/2533433) didn't? Isn't this rather a comment on that, recommending "absolute paths" for logs? It in no way prevents the log entries being copied to Apache's error log, and thus doesn't answer the question (see my comment there).

Comment: This is what We use, It does not get duplicated to the Apache logs, And no its not the same as bberg's answer reflects the relative path, you have to define the absoulute path

Comment: I had absolute paths in my configs from the very beginning (as the question shows). Still have multiple entries in the error_log. And as stated in my comment on the other question, even the docs say *Messages at levels 1–3 are **always copied** to the Apache error log*, so there's obviously nothing to help it. I meanwhile even got used to it, so it's no longer an open issue to me. // Thanks for the pointer, though.

Comment: Ohh I may have missed that, We have log levels configured upto 5. thats why i dont see it.